# Load new content and keep track of oldest article

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have never actually learned how to create a blog or anything the like up to now. I would like to create a personal portfolio/homepage, which will load older articles as soon as the user pushes the "load more" button. Now, I have it all set up, but I don't really know how to keep track of the oldest article ID.

As mentioned, here I load articles from a php script via AJAX.

```
$('#more_articles_button').click(function () {

    $.ajax({ url: kBaseUrl+"content_loader.php",
        data: {
               action: 'load_more_articles', 
               article_id: 'insert_lowest_article_id'
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {

                 $('#articles_container').append(output);

        }
    });

});
```

Here I would like to get the last article's id and send it to the php script. How do I get hold of it ?

Comment: You've not posted any sample data or given any clue how the data is structured. There's no way we can answer your question.

Comment: @MikeW Well, does it really matter ? I think it is clear from the question that I DO HAVE access to the article id. I just want to create a connection between the php and JS part. I am looking for a generic answer more than a specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the article id in the id's attribute of your article's div and a common class in them (say, 'article'), and, using JQuery, iterate through them to get the maximum value:

```
var max_id = 0;
$('.article').each(function(i, object) {
    curr_id = $(object).attr('id');
    if (curr_id > max_id)
        max_id = curr_id;
});

//Afterwards, your ajax JQuery call
```

Comment: I like that.  I'll try that

Comment: By the way, I used the last child selector `$('#articles_container > div:last-child').attr('id');` of my article container to get the last article. I don't think I need to iterate over all the articles as the last article is always the oldest one...